# What are the possible values of $x$ here?

Tags: inequality

> Suppose that $ABC$ is a $3$-digit number and we decrease tens
> digit by $(x-2)$ and increase hundreds digits by $x$. If the number
> increases by more than $560$, what are the possible values of $x$?

Suppose that our new number is

$$(ABC)' = ABC-10(x-2)+10^2x$$

leading us to

$$(ABC)'-ABC = -(x-2)10+10^2x>560$$

and

$$x\geq 7$$

Thus, $x\in \{7, 8\}$ will work.

Comment: @Blue Thanks, edited.

Comment: What you've shown is just "at best, x = 7, 8, 9 COULD work". Are you sure that $x = 9 $ can work? What's an example of such a 3 digit number?

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks, edited

Comment: Note that you have not shown that "7, 8 WILL work".  What you have is a necessary BUT NOT sufficient condition. You need to prove sufficiency another way (like finding a suitable example)